# Exporting layer features in existing Excel file with given column order in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, export, vector-layer, table-to-excel

When Exporting Layer attributes to Excel, file columns are arranged as per their back-end database.

I want to export layer attributes to excel and I want the columns to be arranged in specific order for example if in QGIS the order of column is `"column_a", "column_b", "column_c", "column_d"` in Excel I want it to be `"column_a", "column_c", "column_b", "column_d"` and may be skip some columns.

I've read many solutions but they all are just one time solution, in my work i need to export  multiple layer attributes daily i want to write a code for that, but i have no python experience.

Can anyone guide me with this task?

Comment: You could try running refactor fields in the graphical modeler, this will allow you to automate the process without any python and refactor allows you to re-organize your columns

Comment: I've tried it, but it does not help.

Comment: I have created a model that refactors the fields and it works fine for me, if you have different columns every time the approach won't be much help. What issue are you having?

Comment: as per my knowledge using refractor needs to upload template every time i need to export file, also it create a shapefile which then will be exported to excel.

Comment: If the attributes are different every time then yes this approach won't help much but if they follow the same template you can save your refactor settings in a model.

Answer (score 7):

I have created a rough model
[image]

You will need to load in your template attributes and re-organise as desired

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will automatically refactor fields accourding to the current order of the attribute table. Reorder the fields as you like, adjust the layer name and:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points")[0] #Change points to the name of your layer

#Create a dictionary of current field order and the field properties:
default_fields = {f.name():{'expression':f.name(),'length':f.length(),'name':f.name(),'precision':f.precision(),'sub_type':f.subType(),'type':f.type(),'type_name':f.typeName()} for f in layer.fields()}

#For example to get the properties of the KKOD field:
#default_fields['KKOD']
#{'expression': 'KKOD', 'length': 5, 'name': 'KKOD', 'precision': 0, 'sub_type': 0, 'type': 2, 'type_name': 'Integer'}

#Find the current field order accourding to the attribute table configuration:
tableconfig  = layer.attributeTableConfig()
new_field_order = [c.name for c in tableconfig.columns()] #The current order in the attribute table

#Remap the fields 
newfieldmap = [default_fields[newfield] for newfield in new_field_order if newfield in default_fields]

processing.runAndLoadResults("native:refactorfields", {'INPUT':layer,
    'FIELDS_MAPPING':newfieldmap,'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})
```

[image]