Export QGIS attribute table as Excel sheet changes column order and sorting
In the attribute table of a layer in QGIS, I can re-organize my columns and sort my data according to my needs. When I export my layer as an Excel file, both my column organization and sorting disappear. Is there a way to keep both for my Excel sheet? At least the column organization would be helpful.

You might use the Refactor Fields tool in Processing - Vector Table.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/448771/exporting-layer-features-in-existing-excel-file-with-given-column-order-in-qgis/448783#448783

Column order in QGIS attribute tables is just for visualisation purposes - it's arbitrary/changeable and not reflective of the underlying data structure. This is where GIS programs (which treat data like it's in a relational database where column order doesn't matter, because data is referred to by values or column names) is different from Excel (treats data like it's in a spreadsheet where data is referenced based on column and row order).
To change the underlying column order itself, you can't use the attribute table. You need to use the Refactor Fields processing tool and move the columns around there, then save the layer (as a new one or overwriting your original layer). If you are working off a template, I would recommend you set it up with the column order the way you need it to be from the start, and then proceed with your workflow.
Edit: or you can use the attribute table order along with the Python script linked by @Bera : Exporting layer features in existing Excel file with given column order in QGIS
